# Comma placement after name

Tags: commas, names

I've always been confused where I would place a comma when introducing someone by name then detailing their place of work. For example:

> The visiting professor is Dr. John Smith of the University of Chicago.

Would commas be needed in this instance and if so, where would I place them?

Comment: It's fine as is.

Comment: Yours is fine, or you could use "The visiting professor is Dr. John Smith, of the University of Chicago." This is an issue of style, not grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of ***Comma*** in your case:

Actually the first thing to know is that there are generally only few correct options:

one before and one after the name/title or to separate the elements in a series or a punctuation mark that separates words, clauses, or ideas within a sentence or no commas at all.

While a comma after the title may be correct on rare occasions (which don’t concern us here), a comma only before a name or title is wrong.

for example:

Incorrect:My friend Cleo, is a wonderful singer.

Correct:My friend Cleo is a wonderful singer.

**Reference:** 
https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp

Answer (score -1):

A comma would be not be completely out of place if the sentence was worded: Dr. John Smith, of the University of Chicago, is the visiting professor.